# React styled-components S. notation when using SC from multiple sources

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406396/styled-components-shared-styled-components-when-using-s-name-naming-convent), but the answer in my opinion doesn't actually answer anything, it just says "use `$` instead of `S.`"

Let's say I have two `styled-components`:

`src/components/shared/Foo/Foo.tsx`

```
const Foo = styled.p`
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
`;
```

`src/components/Bar/Bar.styles.tsx`

```
const BarWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Then I want to use them both in `Bar.tsx`. The standard case when using SC is importing the SCs belonging to the component dir (or having them in the component file already) like: `import {Bar} from "./Bar.styles"`. The only difference I (and many people for that matter) make, is I do `import * as S from "./Bar.styles"`, so later in code I can reference the styled component like `S.BarWrapper` to distinguish it from other components.

The problem here is: what if I want to also use `Foo` in `Bar.tsx`? I can't do `import * as S from "../shared/Foo/Foo"` because the letter `S` is already "taken" in `Bar.tsx`.

I am wondering if you guys that follow this convention (doesn't have to be `S`, can be `Styled` or `SC` - seen those as well) handle that kind of situation. Is there a good way to do it? Or do I have to compromise and use `Foo` instead of `<something>.Foo`?

Comment: Import and export every component to/from `index.js` file in the components folder as `export {default as [Component Name]} from './[relative path]`, then you can use `import * as S from './components'`

Comment: That's true, but some of them are styled, some of them are not, so the `S.` prefix would be misleading

Comment: It's a React component, do you *really* need to know specifically if any *given* component is a styled-component or just a regular component? Seems a rather odd and extraneous distinction. I mean, I guess if it helps you in some way then why not just append a number, i.e. `import * as S1 from "....";` and `import * as S2 from "....";` and so on?

Comment: I guess that's an option. I actually thought about doing it this way: every component I have consists of 3 files: `index.js` - exporting the component, `<component_name>.tsx` - the actual component, `<component_name>.styles.tsx` - styled components for the component. I can then import the shared styled components in the `*.styles.tsx` file - all that I need for a particular component and import them back in my component or create new SCs in the styles file and then import them. About distinguishing between components and SCs - I created many components and I use MUI, so things can get messy